Is there a function to make my sheet search for texts in different columns



DODIC
NOMENCLATURE
NSN
LOT
SERIAL
QTY




AC21
9MM HP

WMA19K403-022

100


AC21
9MM

WMA19K403-022

900


AC21
9MM



1942


AB57
5.56MM STEEL TIP



1454



I want to take all columns that has a header "DODIC" and make a list on a separate page, I also need to look for the corresponding column that goes with the dodic titles "lot" and move that to the same page. For instance dodic is AB57 and I got 5 different lots. Would it be possible to list the 5 different lots with the dodic on the separate sheet. After that, I need to get the "QTY" for that lot number, so if ever it has multiple of the same lot number for a dodic it will add the QTY together. Maybe I'm overthinking it or there's a simple way to do it I'm just lost.
I tried Dcount but it errored maybe I did something wrong.

Welcome to stackoverflow! Please provide your sample sheet, with your initial output, and also your expected output so that we can further help you. You may use this to provide a markdown table (you may create one with the help of this link ) or an anonymous sample spreadsheet (using this link

Please avoid sharing images of your spreadsheet data as the only source of data to avoid closure of the question.

Please convert the tables on the image as markdown tables. I merely showed the image but I cannot convert the data into markdown tables since your sample data is quite large.

Please read: Why is "Can someone help me?" not a useful question?, and How to ask too, and ask yourself if "I want ..." repeated four times in your question is a better way to ask.....  (I think it is not a better way.....)

Building on @Luuk's point. Phrasing the question with I want... can come across as demanding, especially since everyone here is a volunteer. Remember, Stack Overflow is a resource for solving coding problems, not a free coding service.

You may want to try the query() function.

Further to the suggestion by @doubleunary, have you tried something like =query({Sheet1!A1:F},"select Col1, Col4, Sum(Col6) where Col1 is not null group by Col1, Col4 label sum(Col6) 'QTY'") where the data is on "Sheet1", and the formula is on another sheet in the same spreadsheet. Anyway, For instance dodic is AB57 and i got 5 different lot for that, would you please edit the question to include this in the sample data as well as an example of the expected outcome.

I think that’s the answer to the question, @Tedinoz. The markdown table is the output that the OP wants since the earlier picture only had 1 in its quantity, and you can post your formula as an answer.

Try this formula:
=query({Sheet1!A1:F},
   "select Col1, Col4, Sum(Col6) 
     where Col1 is not null 
     group by Col1, Col4 
     label sum(Col6) 'QTY'"
)

where the data is on "Sheet1", and the formula is on another sheet in the same spreadsheet.

Sample data


Sample output


Using Query to Display and Sum Values with Multiple Different Sheets
@Tedinoz's answer is correct.
You can also add multiple sheets in just 1 query on a formula. This will sum all the QTY across the sheets if the value for DODIC and LOT matches.
Here's the Formula:
 =QUERY({Sheet1!A1:F5;Sheet2!A2:F5;Sheet3!A2:F5}, "SELECT Col1, Col4, SUM(Col6) GROUP BY Col1, Col4 LABEL SUM(Col6) 'Total QTY'")


Example Output
Sheets 1, 2 and 3 has this markdown table similar to your example above:



DODIC
NOMENCLATURE
NSN
LOT
SERIAL
QTY




AC21
9MM HP

WMA19K403-022

100


AC21
9MM

WMA19K403-022

900


AC21
9MM



1942


AB57
5.56MM STEEL TIP



1454



After pasting the formula on a new sheet, this will be the expected output:



DODIC
LOT
Total QTY




AB57

4362


AC21

5826


AC21
WMA19K403-022
3000




Since the given example has the same exact value for DODIC and LOT on Sheets 1-3, the total QTY will be added per match across all the sheets listed on the first parameter of your formula.


Take note that this is based on the image that you provided earlier.


Reference

QUERY function

